# Does acts-as-taggable-on work on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question: does the acts-as-taggable-on gem work on Heroku?

I'been trying but it doesn't seem to work. In my development machine works okay. I'm wondering if it's maybe because Heroku uses PostgreSQL and my local env SQLite and for some reason postgresql is not supported by the special tagging "magic"?

I couldn't find any related info to this, so I would like to know other experiences with this.  I guess is pretty rare since both the gem and heroku are very popular.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `interests' for   "#<About:0x2b35d6125728>":About):

<% unless @user.about.interests.empty? %>
  <p><strong>interests and passions</strong><br />
  <% @user.about.interests.each do |tag| %>
    <%= tag %>, 
  <% end -%></p><% end %>
```

In my `about.rb` model i have

```
acts_as_taggable_on :interests, :music, :movies, :books, :tvs
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [this similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906323/acts-as-taggable-on-on-heroku), you have to run the migration after you `git push heroku master` correct?  do a `heroku rake db:migrate` just in case.  hell I'd even do a `heroku restart` just for fun too.

Oh, and you do have the correct associations between User and About, i hope.

Comment: I thought I did that but it seem i didn't. I tried both and now it works. Thank you!